# Edit Google Colab Jupyter Notebook in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I just found out that in `VSCode` you can define a remote `Jupyter` server and edit the `Jupyter` notebook from within `VSCode`. You only need to define the URI of the `Jupyter` server. I was checking on the `Google Colab` but didn't find an option to get this URI.

Is there an easy way to link both the `VSCode` and `Google Colab`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, this isn't supported for a variety of reasons, e.g., Colab requires authenticating with a Google account, which isn't supported by vanilla Jupyter.

Comment: I see, thanks for the reply. Shall I delete the question or leave it?

Comment: @GeorgiStoyanov I think leaving is better. Because, some "Technical improvement" can solve your problem, some will answer this question with new Tech and the others can solve their own problem like this.